# On IA-automorphism group

Tags: group-theory

For a group $G$, $IA(G):=\{ \alpha \in Aut(G):g^{-1}\alpha (g)\in G',\forall g\in G\}$ and $IA_z (G):=\{ \alpha\in IA(G):\alpha (z)=z,\forall z\in Z(G)\}$. Assume that $G$ is a finite perfect group. Is $|IA_z (G)|=|Aut(G)|$?

My try: Since $G$ is perfect, then $G=G'$. Then $$IA(G)=\{ \alpha \in Aut(G):g^{-1}\alpha (g)\in G'=G,\forall g\in G\}=Aut(G).$$ But I couldn't prove that $IA_z(G)=IA(G)$.

My question comes from the paper "On IA-isoclinism of groups" in https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/S0219498823502092 in which:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The perfect group $3.A_6$ has an outer automorphism of order 2 (induced from the conjugation action of an odd permutation in $S_6$) that does not induce the identity on $Z(G)$. So the answer to your question is no. Similarly for $3.A_7$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I edited my question. Could you please tell me Proposition 2.2 is wrong in the paper?